# Android Studio cannot resolve method addRule()

Tags: android, layoutparams

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(containerWidth, fragmentHeight);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

And i get: *error: cannot find symbol method addRule(int)*

Android Studio v 0.4.5

Comment: What are your imports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you used `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(containerWidth, fragmentHeight);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

but the method *addRule* is in the subclass `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` implemented, so you may want to use instead:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(containerWidth, fragmentHeight);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

see [documentation of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int%29)

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(containerWidth, fragmentHeight);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```